# DHCP: is DNS configuration optional?

Tags: dns, dhcp

As suggested by title: is there possibility that after a successful DHCP session, DNS server is not configured?

Comment: Are you asking if DHCP can lease addresses without giving DNS information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. A DHCP server is not required to provide DNS information when it leases an IP address.

[RFC2131](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt) section 4.3.1:

> The server MUST supply as many of the requested parameters as possible and MUST omit any parameters it cannot provide.

So technically, it is required to provide them if requested and if it can provide them. But it need not provide DNS information if it cannot provide them or if the client doesn't specifically request them.

Comment: is there a reference?

Comment: [RFC2131](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt) section 4.3.1: "The server MUST supply as many of the requested parameters as possible and MUST omit any parameters it cannot provide." (So technically, it is required to provide them if requested and if it can provide them. But it need not provide DNS information if it cannot provide them or if the client doesn't specifically request them.)

Comment: What is the host name if I `ping -a` a leased static IP?